# angular does not load my directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I newly start to use angular.but I have some problem to loading my directive.
I want to load my directive as soon as page loaded.

where I load data-show directive

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <article class="row" ng-controller="DataCtrl">
                <input type="button" ng-click="getDataList()" >
                <h1>Some Content Here</h1>
                <ul id="home" bread-crumbs></ul>
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li ng-repeat="data in list" class="col-md-5">
                        <show-data data="data"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
```

showData directive:

```
app.directive('showData', function () {
return{
    restrict: 'E',
    replace:true,
    templateUrl: 'views/directives/datas.directive.html',
    scope: {
        data: "="
    },
    controller:'DataCtrl'

}
```

})

and template I used in:

```
    <div class="well hoverwell">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="col-md-4">{{data.name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="col-md-1">Code:</span>
        <span class="col-md-1">{{data.id}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="col-md-1">accountability:</span>
        <span class="col-md-1">{{data.parent}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="col-md-1">&nbsp;:</span>
        <span class="col-md-1">{{data.definition}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
    .controller('DataCtrl', function ($scope, DataService, $log) {

        $scope.getDataList = function () {
            var list = DataService.getDataList(1);
            list.then(
                function (result) {
                    $log.info(result);
                    $scope.dataList = result;

                }, function (status) {
                    $log.error(status)
                    $scope.msg = "error " + status + " has been occur,please report to admin ";
                });
        };

    });
```

and when I run my app it does not work .
when I watch it in chorome development tools my directive is comment

[image]

what is my problem.How can I call this directive as soon as page load.
thx

Comment: Angular doesn't support self-closing elements so try to use <show-data data="data"></show-data>

Comment: don't reference the parent controller either in directive. That's not what `controller` is for

Comment: I got what is  what the problem,the list in ng-repeat="data in list" have not filled yet. and that`s why this pice of code is comment.How can I wait to my service fetch list data and after that I load my directive my directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed, you see empty list because your dataList in ng-repeat is not filled yet.

But you have some errors in your code:

1. First of all - you should never use one controller twice. So you need to create separate controller for your directive.
2. `replace` directive parameter is deprecated, better not to use it.
3. In your `DataCtrl` you set the `dataList` variable: `$scope.dataList = result;`, but in HTML you refer to `list` variable: `<li ng-repeat="data in list" class="col-md-5">`.

Maybe that [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vlze3HGg8f1kKh4HaVqd?p=preview) will help you to figure out with your code.